# Can I travels to other countries in Schengen area with a national visa (type D) of Italy?

Tags: visas, schengen

I am a volunteer in Italy since January 2017 and I have a national visa type D - Multi - 190 days. I'm staying in Italy 6 months until my project is finished in July 2017.

This is my first time in Europe, so I would like to make a trip to some other countries in the Schengen area at the end of June, before I return to my native country in the beginning of July. I'm afraid that I can't do it if I don't have a residence permit for Italy. They gave me an appointment on the 23rd of May at the Police department to apply for a residence permit, but I think it will be too late to get the decision (normally, it takes 2 or 3 months).

Can I use my visa to travel without residence permit? If it is possible, do I need prepare any document or paper to travel with my visa?

Answer (score 0):

> Long sojourn or "national" Visas (NV), which are only valid for visits
>   that are longer than 90 days (type D), with one or more entries, in
>   the territory of the Schengen State whose diplomatic mission issued
>   the visa. **Holders of type D visas are permitted to circulate freely in
>   Schengen countries other than the issuing one for a period of not more
>   than 90 days per half-year and only if the visa is valid.**

http://www.esteri.it/mae/en/ministero/servizi/stranieri/ingressosoggiornoinitalia/visto_ingresso/tipologie_visto_durata.html